# Retrieve an image from the web in java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to read an image that resides somewhere on the web from my Java program. So far I have successfully loaded an image by using the following code.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo4.png");
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
```

What I want to know is why this code (which is the first i tried) does not work:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo4.png"));
```

This would have the benefit of giving me a `BufferedImage`. Also, how can I make the above code block until the image is loaded? I know I can use an `ImageObserver`, but is there a simpler way?

When I try the second option, I get this exception:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) cannot refer to a URL.

Although I haven't tried it, there appears to be a [`ImageIO.read(URL)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.net.URL)) method, which can take an URL as the input as an [`URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) object.

I would presume it would be called as follows:

```
ImageIO.read(new URL("http://url/to/my/image.png"));
```

Comment: :D i was just about to mark this question as answered since i found the solution you proposed on my own just now. Thank you anyway your answer was correct.

Answer (score 1):

File objects cant read from URLs

Comment: Although the solution has been posted, this is the real answer to the question. java.io.File can't read URLs.

Comment: you are correct. I know i should promote this answer since it responds to my question. I chose the other one though because it offered a solution as well :D I should have rephrased the question i guess...